# If $f$ is twice differentiable in $(-1,1)$ and $f(0) = f'(0) =0$, does $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty f(1/n) $ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

In calculus, I'm trying to understand if the following forces the convergence of the sum. I think it does, but I have no clue as how to prove it.

Similar to subject line, here is the question:

> If $f$ is twice differentiable in $(-1,1)$ and $f(0) = f'(0) =0$, does $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty f(1/n)$ converge?

Comment: Yes if $f$ is twice continuously differentiable. In fact, yes if $f''$ is bounded in a neighborhood of zero.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I don't think we need twice *continuously* differentiable -- see my answer below. (I say this not to be a pedant, but because I don't want to give an incorrect answer.)

Comment: Yes, you are right, I was complicating things in my approach: Assume boundedness of $f''$ near $0$. By the mean value theorem, $f(1/n)=f(1/n)-f(0)=f'(\zeta_n)/n$ for some $\zeta_n\in(0,1/n)$. Applying the theorem again, $f'(\zeta_n)=f''(\eta_n)\zeta_n$ for some $\eta_n\in(0,\zeta_n)$. Now, $f''(\eta_n)$ is bounded as $n$ varies, and $\zeta_n/n\le1/n^2$, so the series converges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem), we can write $f(x)=cx^2+h(x)x^2$, where $c$ is a constant and $h$ tends to $0$ as $x$ tends to $0$. This means we have the bound

$$|f(x)| < Ax^2$$

where $A$ is some positive real constant. Then your assertion follows immediately from comparison with the series $$\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}.$$

Comment: How are you getting the cube there? All you know is that $f(x)=cx^2+h(x)x^2$ where $h\to0$. Then you probably mean $|f(x)|\le Kx^2$ for some $K\ge 0$ in the first display.

Comment: How do I know that I can actually represent the function with the Taylor series? How can I conclude that f is analytical?

Comment: @vondip There is no Taylor series here, and no assumption of analyticity; just a basic Taylor polynomial with remainder. This is all explained in the link provided in the first line of the answer.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Sorry, I misread the statement of Taylor's theorem. It should be right now.

Comment: I see, since we only know that f(x) is differentiable twice, we can use the polynomial taylor expansion, but we're unable to develop an entire series. and since that's the case we make less assumptions about the function and need to require less (hence no analyticity is required)

Comment: @vondip Yes. The key fact is that we have control over the error term.